# Migration of japanese data to Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am into data migration team, right now we got a project of Japanese database migration. We need to migrate all japanese data to our Oracle database. After which we need to compare Japanese data between source and target database. I just want to know is it possible to write normal SQL queries for Japanese data in SQL server, will it work and What are the risks associated with this?

Comment: What is the source database character set? Can you keep that? Conversions might be lossy for the more unusual characters.

Comment: Hi Thilo,I will get back asap. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem - SQL Querys in Japan are the same as in the other parts of the world.
There may occur some problems in case of data formating + converting (string format, datetime, collation) + string comparison so I suggest some testing before the whole migration process.